# How to create custom Push Notification for my Own App?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I want to make my own Push Notification that works for my Own App. I know that I have to manage all that threw the Web-Service. But I am wonder about how to make that push Notification.

So can any-one tell me how to make that Custom Push Notification?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it is using Urban Airship - http://urbanairship.com/

Check all the guides/docs on their site, as they explain everything very well, you'll need to register with Google for a C2DM auth token, and set up a free account with Urban Airship. Then it's just a case of configuring you manifest and a few other classes. Dig around in both the API docs and the guide. The urban airship jars have very good support for logging too, so if you can't get it working, check logcat and this will usually give you a good description of why it's failing.

You can also do some other cool stuff like use the notification to trigger running some code etc.

The notifications can be sent from Urban Airships site/UI, or via a JSON payload via a HTTP POST request from your web server to Urban Airship.

Without Urban airship, your stuck creating loads of server infrastructure, Urban Airship has a very generous free package (1000000 free notifications!) and also supports cross platform, so you could send notifications to the Android, BB and iOS versions of your apps from one place.

Comment: Really a nice Answer. Thanks Man. But in case if i want to make my own notification then what should i have to do ?

Comment: I haven't had any experience doing it myself, but here would be a good place to start researching it - http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html