# HTTP request spamming in turn based game

Tags: android, http, multiplayer

I made a turn based Android game, which is using HTTP protocol for multiplayer.

Everything is working fine, but the problem comes, when the game has to check, if other player made a move. Currently this is solved by "spamming" HTTP get requests every 0.5 second.

Do you think this is a viable solution? Is 0.5 seconds too fast? Or do you have any other idea, which I could use to check for other player move without usage of sockets?

Comment: Have you considered a push notification?

Comment: Is there a server or is it peer to peer with direct IP connection?

Comment: Might want to checkout using something like WebSockets, that will keep a persistent connection that data can just flow across.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling What do you mean with push notification? How that would help? Aren't they used to show notifications?

Comment: @Zhuinden There is a server with database. Application uses .php files to contact database and get informations.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10412488

Comment: They can be used to show notification messages, but they can also be used to push events down from the server that your application reacts to.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting,

If your game is a turn based (and don't need a real time respond), it will be fine. 0.5 seconds is a good time (to me), just playing to know for sure.

This answer is based on what I think about the game, maybe if the requests are heavy, it will be a problem (so, make sure that one request is executed after another and one request brings everything that changed, trying to avoid stacks of commands )

If you want something more realtime, search for websockets, you can make connections that can stay alive forever (and using nodeJs on the server side, for example, you can answer when an action occurs).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will probably leave it as it is now (requests are executed in this order: request > answer > 0.5 >request > ..., so it doesn't stack), but I will definitely look into websockets and node.js. I realized the idea with HTTP requests is stupid after I already implemented it. I will surely use websockets or something else for my next app.